# ¿Cómo ejecutar una síntesis de voz mediante SpeechSynthesizer sin que el Form se congele?

Tags: c#, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Soy algo novato con los subprocesos y tengo duda al momento de realizar una tarea que tarda bastante en ejecutarse, lo pondré en contexto para que sea mas claro.

Estoy creando una aplicación que me lee el texto que contiene un `TextBox`, sin usar hilos al momento de que me comienza a leer texto del `Textbox`, el formulario completo se congela y no es posible dar click a un botón para detener el lector porque el proceso principal esta ocupado con esa tarea.

Por ese motivo acudí a usar hilos, solo que no me funcionan como esperaba. Usando hilos también me sucede lo mismo y no me deja realizar ninguna acción hasta que el proceso finalice. También leí que usar `BackgroundWorker` me podría ayudar pero es el mismo problema.

```
    using System.Speech.Synthesis;
    using System.Threading;

    SpeechSynthesizer _synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    List<VoiceInfo> _vocesInfo = new List<VoiceInfo>();
    double Rate = 0, volumen = 0;
    int indice;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //carga el combobox con las voces disponibles en el S.O.
        foreach (InstalledVoice voice in _synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices()
        {
            _vocesInfo.Add(voice.VoiceInfo);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        volumen = bunifuTrackbar1.Value;
        Rate = bunifuTrackbar2.Value;
        indice = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

        Thread leer = new Thread(leer_texto);
        if (!leer.IsAlive)
        {
            leer.Start();
        }
    }
    public void leer_texto()
    {

        String nombre = _vocesInfo.ElementAt(indice).Name;
        _synthesizer.SelectVoice(nombre);

        _synthesizer.Volume = (int)volumen;
        _synthesizer.Rate = (int)Rate;
        Invoke(new Action(() => _synthesizer.Speak(richTextBox1.Text)));
    }
    //Con este boton quiero parar al lector sin la necesidad de que termine 
    //de leer el texto completo
    private void bunifuImageButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (leer.IsAlive)
        { 
            leer.Abort();
        }        
    }
```

Comment: La solución es async - await, dale una mirada y si tienes dudas, aquí te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Como dice Mauricio, "await - async".
Hay varias formas de trabajar con multi-threading pero para lo que pides esa es la solución.

Comment: `SpeechSynthesizer .SpeakAsync()` no devuelve un `Task` por lo que no es posible usar `async` ni `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas múltiples hilos lo que necesitas es una ejecución asíncrona.

Lamentablemente el API de `SpeechSynthesizer` es antigüo y no soporta asíncronía basada en `Task` (los keywords `async` y `await`) sino basado en eventos, por lo que dispone su propia forma de ejecutarlo asíncronamente mediante el método `SpeakAsync()`

`_synthesizer.Speak()` devuelve un objeto `Prompt` que debes almacenar en tu form ya que para poder detener la ejecución del `SpeechSynthesizer`existe un método llamado `SpeakAsyncCancel()` al cual se le pasa como parámetro el `Prompt`.

Finalmente te recomiendo que el botón de *Detener* este desactivado hasta que no comienze el sintetizador y desactivar el boton de *Iniciar* y activar el botón de *Detener* cuando comience la síntesis de voz. Igualmente cuando acabe la sítesis, ya sea porque se acabó de leer el texto o porque se detuvo con el botón *Detener*, se vuelva a activar el botón de *Iniciar* y desactivar el botón de *Detener*. Esto debido a que no es posible mediante la misma instancia reproducir dos voces al mismo tiempo y si presionas varias veces el botón *Iniciar* se encolarán varias tareas de síntesis de voz y se ejucutarán una tras otra, reemplazando el `prompt` actual con lo cual ya no va a ser posible detener el sintetizador de forma manual, a menos que la lógica se complique bastante más para soportar estos casos.

Te dejo el ejemplo completo aquí:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly SpeechSynthesizer _synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        readonly List<VoiceInfo> _vocesInfo = new List<VoiceInfo>();
        Prompt _prompt;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var voice in _synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                _vocesInfo.Add(voice.VoiceInfo);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
            }
        }

        private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bunifuImageButton1.Enabled = false;
            bunifuImageButton2.Enabled = true;

            var nombre = _vocesInfo[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Name;
            _synthesizer.SelectVoice(nombre);
            _synthesizer.Volume = bunifuTrackbar1.Value;
            _synthesizer.Rate = bunifuTrackbar2.Value;

            _synthesizer.SpeakCompleted += (sender2, e2) =>
            {
                bunifuImageButton1.Enabled = true;
                bunifuImageButton2.Enabled = false;
            };
            _prompt = _synthesizer.SpeakAsync(richTextBox1.Text);
        }

        private void bunifuImageButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _synthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancel(_prompt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si deseas el proyecto completo, lo subí a GitHub: [AsyncSpeechSynthesizerDemoSOes](https://github.com/carlosmunozrodriguez/AsyncSpeechSynthesizerDemoSOes/tree/Version_SOes)

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas, Carlos Muñoz con eso ya me has ayudado bastante, ya con eso puedo seguir con el proyecto. Gracias

Comment: me surgió una duda, es posible modificar el volumen y velocidad mientras se esta ejecutando y que este se aplique sin tener que detener el sintetizador?